# Python TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, linear-algebra

I am trying to write a function that performs backsubstitution on a matrix already in echelon form, but every time I try to access an index of my matrix I get - TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable.  I've been working with this for hours now and am getting really frustrated, although I am probably overlooking an obvious detail.  Here is my code:

```
def backsubstitution(B):
    """
    return the reduced row echelon form matrix of B
    """
    G = B.copy()
    m, n = np.shape(G)
    pivot = 0
    # To start, let i = 0
    i = 0
    # If row i is all zeros, or if i exceeds the number of rows in A, stop
    while(i != m):
        # If row i has a nonzero pivot value, divide row i by its pivot value to
        # create a 1 in the pivot position
        # First, find the pivot position
        pivPos = 0
        while(G[i][pivPos] == 0.0):
            pivPos += 1
            if(pivPos == n-1 and G[i][pivPos] == 0.0):
                return G
        # Now divide row i by its pivot value if the pivot is not already 1
        if(G[i][pivPos] != 1):
            pivot = G[i][pivPos]
            for k in range(n):
                if(G[i][k] == 0.0):
                    G[i][k] == 0.0
                else:
                    G[i][k] = (G[i][k] / pivot)
        # Use row reduction operations to create zeros in all positions above the
        # pivot
        if(i != 0):
            for l in range(i):
                G = rowReduce(G, i, i-1, pivPos)         
        # Let i = i + 1
        i += 1
    return G
```

If anyone can help, I would be immensely grateful.

Edit: The hashed comments are the steps for the backsubstitution algorithm as given by my professor.

2nd Edit: rowReduce is a function provided by the professor

3rd Edit: Here's rowReduce:

```
def relError(a, b):
    """
    compute the relative error of a and b
    """
    with warnings.catch_warnings():
        warnings.simplefilter("error")
        try:
            return np.abs(a-b)/np.max(np.abs(np.array([a, b])))
        except:
            return 0.0

def rowReduce(A, i, j, pivot):
    """
    reduce row j using row i with pivot pivot, in matrix A
    operates on A in place
    """
    factor = A[j][pivot] / A[i][pivot]
    for k in range(len(A[j])):
        # we allow an accumulation of error 100 times larger than a single computation
        # this is crude but works for computations without a large dynamic range
        if relError(A[j][k], factor * A[i][k]) < 100 * np.finfo('float').resolution:
            A[j][k] = 0.0
        else:
            A[j][k] = A[j][k] - factor * A[i][k]
```

I am calling the function on a matrix M already in echelon form  : 
backSub = backsubstitution(M)

Comment: Which line are you getting error? How are you calling this function? And show the function `rowReduce()` .

Comment: Ouch, your variables need much better names. It makes debugging much easier.

Comment: @electrometro: I dunno. The one-character names are well established in linear algebra. (Such as using capital letters for matrices, `n`, `m` for dimensions, etc.) Using longer names just to satisfy PEP8 serves no purpose.

Answer (score 4):

Notice that the doc string of `rowReduce` says it "operates in place". That means it *changes* the array you pass it, rather than giving you a new one back. If this wasn't explicitly documented, another big indicator is that it lacks any `return` statement.

That means that this line:

```
G = rowReduce(G, i, i-1, pivPos)
```

should just be:

```
rowReduce(G, i, i-1, pivPos)
```

Since `rowReduce` doesn't return a new array (or indeed explicitly `return` at all), its return value will be `None`. When you reassign that result back to `G`, it will be `None` when you go back to the top of the loop and try to do this:

```
G[i][pivPos]
```

Which will give you the `TypeError` you see.